delete an row with join
i use oracle 19c, i try to delete a row via a join
delete from periodic_info pi
join pub p on pi.id_pub=p.id_pub
join depot d on p.id_depot=d.id_depot
where d.id_depot = 14915 and p.version=0;

I just get:
"SQL command not properly ended"

Does Oracle really support that non-standard syntax?

From which table do you want to delete? You can do DELETE (SELECT your query), but this will only delete from all tables if the FK are defined with delete cascade.

Why join? You want to delete rows from periodic_info, right? Then delete from that table and put your conditions in the where clause: delete from periodic_info where id_pub in (select p.id_pub from pub p join depot d using (id_depot) where d.id_depot = 14915 and p.version=0);

@ThorstenKettner There's nothing wrong with JOIN. As said, they can simply write DELETE (SELECT). If they want to delete from all affected tables, they will write SELECT *, if they want to delete from periodic_info only, they will write SELECT pi.*

@Jonas Metzler: Thank you for this information. I didn't know this syntax was allowed. I've tested that and found out that this does indeed work, but it always deletes from only the last table in the chain. ON DELETE CASCADE gets ignored, and SELECT * doesn't make a difference either. https://dbfiddle.uk/iunqBpOF

@ThorstenKettner I used this syntax in my test DB and it worked fine, deleted from all affected tables. I don't see the reason why it fails in your fiddle. That's strange ;)
